# Load an html element from amazon's s3

Tags: html, angular, amazon-s3, dynamic-content

I am aware it is possible to reference images stored in s3 via the `src` property, But what if I want to load something more complex, like a section of static html. Are there any ways to go about simply pulling html down for use/insertion into the DOM (similar to a rest call, I suppose)?

I would imagine the css would be inline in this scenario, but that would be the next challenge to face.

(for reference, I'm in an angular framework attempting to implement a section of a page that would be rendered via code stored in s3, so it would be easy enough to update it without deploying the codebase)

Comment: Q: it is possible to reference images stored in s3 via the src property?  A: Sure: just "GET" the URL.  Q: But what if I want to load something more complex, like a section of static html? A: 1) You'd need a web scraping tool or library: https://hevodata.com/learn/8-best-web-scraping-tools/  ... OR ... you'd structure your app to pull "static" files (HTML, images, mp3 clips, etc) from a CDN: [Powering server-side rendering by offloading static assets to CDN for Angular apps](https://blogs.halodoc.io/powering-server-side-rendering-by-offloading-static-assets-to-cdn-for-angular-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have an API that will return a JSON file of format (just a rough assumption):

```
{htmlCodeAlongWithStyle:'Code in string'}
```

Here we are not creating a separate style sheet instead using style property of individual HTML components.

Now to embed code just create a div tag and set the innerHTML to the value of htmlCodeAlongWithStyle property of json.
Example:

```
<div [innerHTML]='variableStoringAPIResponse.htmlCodeAlongWithStyle'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to see if [CDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) fit your use case:

- [Powering server-side rendering by offloading static assets to CDN for Angular apps](https://blogs.halodoc.io/powering-server-side-rendering-by-offloading-static-assets-to-cdn-for-angular-apps/)

Since you're using Amazon S3, I would encourage you to look at [Amazon Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).  But you have many other options - including simply serving static content directly from your S3 instance.